# ExecCondition doesn't prevent start of service

Tags: service, systemd

I have a service file with an `ExecCondition` that, when exits with `status=1/FAILURE`, doesn't prevent the start of the daemon.

Which I believe, based on the documentation, should prevent the daemon from starting as well as prevent all other `ExecStartPre` commands from running.

> when an ExecCondition= command exits with exit code 1 through 254 (inclusive), the remaining commands are skipped and the unit is not marked as failed.

[systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=)

I put in a condition that should fail every time in an obvious way. `ExecCondition=-sh -c 'exit(1)'`

Here's the service file (with names changed to protect the innocent).

```
[Unit]
Description=Application
Wants=x-ray.service yankee.service zulu.service
Requires=alpha.service bravo.service
After=x-ray.service charlie.service bravo.service

[Service]
ExecCondition=-sh -c 'exit(1)'
ExecStartPre=-sh -c 'prestartShellScript.sh'
ExecStart=/opt/app/app argument1 argument2
WatchdogSec=10
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
WorkingDirectory=/opt/app
TimeoutSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I start the service, using `systemctl status app` I see this showing the app is running and the other processes also ran:

```
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-07 18:06:57 UTC; 6s ago
    Process: 33783 ExecCondition=/bin/sh -c exit(1) (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 33796 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c prestartShellScript.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 33827 (app)
      Tasks: 19 (limit: 4177)
     Memory: 101.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/app.service
             └─33827 /opt/app/app argument1 argument2
```

I've also changed my `ExecCondition` to `ExecStartPre` but I see the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-` from `-sh` in `ExecCondition=-sh -c 'exit 1'`

Unix stack exchange is a little more active for `systemd` so I cross posted over there. [See answer on stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659647/execcondition-doesnt-prevent-start-of-service)